# Got a 70 euro used guitar, but frets are rather flat and don't really sound good, what to do?

Tags: guitar, maintenance, beginner

Hello so i bought a guitar in order to learn how to play, went through a few chords and it was rather annoying that some frets are pretty flat so if you press them near the opposite end, it starts buzzing and it's pretty annoying since you don't get a good sound. If you press right near the fret it's pretty fine. They seem pretty flat so i think that might be the problem. or maybe the nut? Was thinking of filing the edges down a bit if possible.

Otherwise i like the guitar, stays in tune properly and all that, don't really care much for the pickups, just the frets are a bit too annoying and the nut seems pretty meh as well. It was an old fender japanese copy or something and couldn't resist... now thinking if it was worth it or not. It vibrates nicely when played for what it's worth and i like that.

Comment: That’s normal. You want to fret as close to the fret as possible. 70€ Is a pretty low price for a guitar.

Comment: yeah, but when you do something like A chord, it's pretty hard to put them all close to the fret.

Comment: True. But after 5 - 10 years of practice it becomes automatic and easy.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it is a low price, true. That doesn't necessarily reflect in the condition, playability , sound of it, though. Several of my guitars came along at 1/10 of their value, through judicious buying, searching, etc. All good, playable, not reflecting the prices paid. Yes, I'm tight !

Comment: I think OP means that the fretwire has been worn down so that it's shallow, and the crown is flat, with sharp edges. Might post an answer to that later, otherwise just get them replaced.

Comment: Show the guitar to someone with more experience.  They'll be able to tell if it's fine, needs a setup, a cleaning, fret polishing, or refretting.  Please don't take a file to it :)  Let a luthier do it.  If you want to do it yourself get the right tools (fretting files), do some research online, and consider you might destroy your guitar while doing it.  Also as mentioned it's normal for all guitars that you need to fret as close as possible to the fret.  Have fun playing! (p.s. there's other fingering for that A chord that help bring your fingers closer to the fret...)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem on *your* guitar, it's a problem for *every* guitar. The basic idea *is* that you press down on the string/s as close to the fretwire as possible. That makes the angle of the string on the wire nice and sharp, and then the string doesn't buzz.

Yes, there's also the problem of multiple fingers when playing chords. Then it's a compromise. Get as close as you can, and if needed, press harder with those fingers that can't make it close to the wire.

Welcome to the fascinating world of Guitar. As Todd says, 5-10 yrs should do it, but more practising will bring that timescale down. You may find that the strings are too high generally, and the *'action'* needs adjusting. That may help. Ask your teacher.

Comment: Ah ok, so then i don't need to do anything more to it. I thought of trying to file the frets on one side a bit so that it would be a more steep angle so that maybe it won't buzz anymore. Though i probably will do stuff with the nut.

Comment: O.k. Bear in mind that once the nut is too low, you'll probably have to replace it and start again.